# What is the maximum number of rails instances a single 256 MB RAM rackspace cloud server can support?

Tags: cloud-computing, ruby-on-rails, architecture

I know it is a vague and ambiguous question.

I want to know just out of curiosity. How many instances of a rails app can I host on server with 256 MB RAM [Cheapest option on Rackspace]?

Assumptions - The app is very simple with 100-200 CRUD operations/day. 
            - Database server is on a separate server.

Comment: How much RAM does one instance take?  What are the VSIZE/RSS figures in top?

Comment: I mean, what are the figures after your 1 instance has started up, and has serviced at least 1 typical request?

Answer (score 1):

I would say one or two.